# How to include existing code/class file when compiling in Java

Tags: java, class, compiler-construction

I am a complete newbie with Java. I use notepad++ to write Java code, and then compile and execute using command line on the **Windows Platform**

How do I reuse existing code or a class file? For instance, I have written a class in file **A.java** (with the corresponding compiled class file available) and wish to use that class in **B.java**. Do I need to specify it in the **B.java** file (sort of lie c/c++) or using compiler options. What compiler options?

Comment: If you are learning java, start using one of the many IDEs around. My choice in intellij, followed by netbeans/eclise/..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use import the A.java class in B.java like this

```
import A.java;
```

By doing like this A class will be available in B class.

[*Java Packages Tutorial*](http://www.jarticles.com/package/package_eng.html)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `import` statement, and the [Using Package Members](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Use can import classes and packages.

```
    import java.io.*; //packages
    import codes.dir.jar; //classes in your packages
```

I'd advise you to use an IDE for coding java, it would make you debug faster.
I recommend Netbeans or Eclipse || http://www.netbeans.org/  or  http://www.eclipse.org/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not yet using an IDE ... I am still at the "Hello World" stage.